# pytorch xla: The element types of the operands to Pad do not match

Tags: pytorch, tensorflow-xla

(edited to provide and explain a minimal reproducible example)

I am seeing the below error when a backward hook is used with pytorch xla.

- the error is not seen when the pytorch-xla is replaced with normal pytorch (aka pytorch cuda).
- and the error is not seen with pytorch-xla when the line copying the gradient is commented out in the backward hook.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 30, in <module>
    l.backward()
  File "/anaconda3/envs/torch-xla-nightly/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 198, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/torch-xla-nightly/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 99, in backward
    allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
RuntimeError: Error while lowering: f32[1,2,16,16]{3,2,1,0} aten::constant_pad_nd, pad=[0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0], value=0
XLA builder error: Invalid argument: The element types of the operands to Pad do not match.:
Python Frames:
```

The minimal code that creates this error:

```
import torch
import torch_xla
import torch_xla.core.xla_model as xm

def loss(output, target):
    l = torch.sum(output - target)
    return l

model = torch.nn.Sequential(
          # minimal model to reproduce the error
          torch.nn.ConstantPad2d((0, 1, 0, 1), 0),
          torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 2, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2)),
          torch.nn.ConstantPad2d((0, 1, 0, 1), 0),
          torch.nn.Conv2d(2, 2, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2))
        )
model = model.to(xm.xla_device())

def dummyHook(module, gradIn, gradOut):
    # error is not seen if i comment out the below line
    g = gradOut[0].cpu()
    print(str(module))

x = torch.randn((1, 1, 32, 32), device=xm.xla_device(), dtype=torch.float)
target = torch.ones((1, 2, 8, 8), device=xm.xla_device(), dtype=torch.float)

for module in model.modules():
    module.register_backward_hook(dummyHook)

y = model(x)
l = loss(y, target)
l.backward()
```

what could be going wrong ?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] that shows your current project state in a *minimal* fashion. Please also share which portions are likely causing the problem by manually narrowing down the scope yourself first.

Comment: @dennlinger, shared a minimal reproducible example and also narrowed it down to a single line in a backward hook.